# Unable to view SQL Server services

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, errors, sql-server-express

Whenever I enter SQL Server Configuration Manager and choose SQL Server Services I would always get the following error message: "The remote Procedure call failed. [0x800706be]"
everything else works fine but not able to configure SQL Services anymore. has anyone came across this and managed to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still running RTM (or SP1 or SP2 I guess), [SP3 was released recently](https://sqlblog.org/2014/09/28/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-3-is-available) - give that a try and see if it helps fix the Configuration Manager issue.

([Applying a service pack has helped others in a similar scenario](http://thuruinhttp.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/sql-configuration-manager-wmi-errorremote-procedure-call-failed-0x800706be/).)